# Designated initializers - how to make sure all members are set in C++20 at compile time?

Tags: c++, c++20

In C++20 we have designated initializers that are similar to C

They can be used to mimic named arguments:

```cpp
struct Params
{
    int speed;
    bool optimize;
    bool check;
};
void FooArgs(const Object& obj, int speed, bool optimize, bool check);
void Foo(const Object& obj, const Params &params);

// the call:
Foo(obj, {.speed = 42, .optimize = true, .check = true});
```

The problem is that if you add a new data member to `Params` you also need to remember to update all the callers. This is different from adding a new argument to `FooArgs()` - where you'd get a compile error when you forget about the new argument...

Is there a way to enforce all data members are set in `Params`? Ideally at compile-time.

The main problem I see is that designated initializers work with Aggregate types, so they cannot have user-defined constructors.